# Date subtraction with some conditions in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    tkoh.ticketid,
    tkoh.ownergroup,
    tkoh.owndate,
    tck.ACTUALFINISH
FROM 
    tkownerhistory tkoh
LEFT JOIN 
    ticket tck on tck.ticketid = tkoh.ticketid
WHERE 
    tkoh.ticketid IN ('О1253565', 'О1253578') 
    AND tkoh.ownergroup IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 
    tkoh.ticketid, tkoh.owndate;
```

It returns something like this:

[image]

I need to calculate time, which every group owned a record (owndate of current record - owndate of next record), BUT, if there is a final owner, time must be substract from the ACTUALFINISH but not from the next record, as it can be done in prevous. I've done it in [Excel file](https://mega.nz/#!oAEzET5K!UnWHKkY8Ma34UGxFNFXxIMKdLUd52-LtEJ_ZrgH7cFQ) with simple IF, but is it really possible in SQL?

Comment: Your expected output would _greatly_ help here.

Comment: Also, please post data as formatted text, not images

Comment: You want people to open an Excel file posted by a stranger on some web site? On what planet do you live?

Comment: yep I am not opening the Excel File to see what you want.  But to point you in the right direction you will need a CASE expression utilizing LAG() or LEAD() test when not null then use same LAG() lead in your subtraction.  If null then use the ACTUALFINISH in your date subtraction

Comment: If you want us to solve this show us example data and expected result -- your "explanation" is not clear in the slightest.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.*,
       trim(to_char(floor(t.res_sec/60/60),'00'))||':'||trim(to_char(floor(mod(t.res_sec/60,60)),'00'))||':'||trim(to_char(mod(t.res_sec,60),'00')) as res_hhmiss
FROM (SELECT 
        tkoh.ticketid,
        tkoh.ownergroup,
        tkoh.owndate,
        tck.ACTUALFINISH,
        abs(tkoh.owndate - nvl(lead(tkoh.owndate) over(order by tkoh.ticketid, tkoh.owndate), tck.ACTUALFINISH))*24*60*60 as res_sec
      FROM tkownerhistory tkoh
      LEFT JOIN ticket tck on tck.ticketid = tkoh.ticketid
      WHERE tkoh.ticketid IN ('О1253565', 'О1253578') and tkoh.ownergroup is not null
      ORDER BY tkoh.ticketid, tkoh.owndate);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  tkoh.ticketid,
  tkoh.ownergroup,
  tkoh.owndate,
  tck.ACTUALFINISH,

  coalesce(datediff(day, tkoh.owndate, lead(tkoh.owndate) over(order by tkoh.ticketid, tkoh.owndate)),
     datediff(day, tkoh.owndate, tck.ACTUALFINISH)) As Diff

FROM tkownerhistory tkoh
LEFT JOIN ticket tck on tck.ticketid = tkoh.ticketid
WHERE tkoh.ticketid IN ('О1253565', 'О1253578') and tkoh.ownergroup is   not null
ORDER BY tkoh.ticketid, tkoh.owndate;
```